# Keywords as Fields in Logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am new to ELK stack.
My requirement is to read several .log files and analyze the data in Kibana.

In the log file, I have several occurrences of certain keyword, let's say "xyz".

Is there any way, I can create a field for this keyword ("xyz") in the logstash conf file ?

I have googled/youtube/read the materials but grok is using "WORD" pattern which is not going to help as all the String letters will come under "WORD" category.

Please help.

Comment: Could you add some specifics? e.g. dummy data from log files and the desired output?

Comment: Hi @aaaa, Thanks for response
Well, I can't put the exact file. However, Please consider the file in the below template -
<TimeStamp>[xyz] today is monday </br>
<TimeStamp>[abc] I don't care about the day </br>
<TimeStamp>[xyz]Well you should do. </br>

and so on </br>
I want that xyz should be one of the fields.

How can I achieve this ? </br>

Please let me know if any more clarification is required.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a finite number of [xyz]'s?
Do you need all [xyz]'s in an array?

I guess I'm just trying to understand how you want them grouped.

It looks like you're showing us multiple events, in which case you might simply use a pattern to grab the timestamp followed by the field in question.

If you're not interested in capturing all of them, is there anything to distinguish the one [xyz] that you're looking for in the log file?

I'd like to help you out, but this problem seems too abstract as is.

Comment: Also, please understand that the format (template) you've provided can easily be matched, but I suspect that it's not verbatim.

What do your dates look like? Do all lines end with "</br>" or do things simply jump down to the next line?

If you could do a simple substitution on the text you've provided, it'd be helpful. I'm not sure if it's because you're worried about breaking NDA, but I don't think I could provide you anything that'd be remotely helpful to you unless you gave us a more complete example.